# JMeter Parameterization - Get the weather for cities with names that contain spaces

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, openweathermap, jmeter-4.0

I tried to get weather data using cityname from [openweathermap.org](https://openweathermap.org/find). After the comma is the country code. I refer to [this link](https://openweathermap.org/current).
[image]
Here is the CSV data from my excel file, included the country code as well with the comma:

[image]

Here is the CSV Data Set Config in JMeter:

[image]

But when I tried to run with 4 thread group, it returns error:

[image]

When I tried to change the CSV data without the comma, it works fine except for the last row:

[image]

[image]

Question here:

1. Did JMeter cannot read CSV data with comma and spaces?
2. Do I have to change read file from CSV to Notepad?
3. Refer last row of CSV file, I tried to search New York city (with space) but returns error. According to [openweathermap](https://openweathermap.org/find), the search engine is flexible, so I don't know why in this case it cannot read "New York" but can read the city with one word.

Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: What does your CSV look like when you don't open in it Excel? (e.g. Notepad) It might see the `,` and view the country code as a separate column.

Comment: I view it in Notepad, example here: "London,UK"

Comment: I mean if you parse your CSV using `,` it will consider `London,UK` 2 separate columns: `London` & `UK`. Also I think `New York` is giving you issues because it has a space separating the 2 words and it won't work when you pass that into the URI

Comment: okay. How to solve this?

Comment: I believe you have 2 issues: parsing the CSV and passing values to the URI. First one can be solved by changing the Delimiter in  the CSV. Second one can be solved by URL encoding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235528/discussion-between-sabbyna-and-rutger-huijsmans).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the most important screenshot - the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

Most probably you forgot to tick `URL Encode` box next to your `q` parameter.

I don't think space needs encoding, however comma [certainly does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) so you need to change `,` to `%2C` either manually or by ticking the aforementioned box

[image]

If you're having troubles with manually building your HTTP Request samplers be aware that you can just record the associated network call from https://openweathermap.org/find page using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium).

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode value when sending characters as space, use [__urlencode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode)

```
  ${__urlencode(${cityname})}
```

Comment: I tried this but still not working. This is the error: `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 57: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=New+York}&appid=e6f90e2506dfd0f2dbd1ed2d87fe18ef
` i noticed after New+York, got extra bracket there

Comment: How to remove the extra bracket symbol?

Comment: @sabbyna are you sure you didn't add extra `}`?